# observe updateSelectInput based on first selection

Tags: r, select, input, shiny

My server.R has the following code, I would like my Shiny app to chose States based on the Country Selection, but it shows all states in the second line. I guess here, `observe` is only observing not performing any action.

```
  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

      observe({
          ddf = df[df$Date>=input$daterange[1] & df$Date<=input$daterange[2],]
          updateSelectInput(session, "Country", choices = ddf$Country)
          ddf1 = subset(ddf, grepl(input$Country, ddf$State))
          updateSelectInput(session, "State", choices =  ddf1$State)  
            })

    }
```

Based on above selection, I want to pass some data frame for plotting. When I select different country it is changing states list for a second and going back to all First country's state list. I really appreciate if some one can show an example here.
My ui.R code is below

```
 sidebarPanel(
    wellPanel(dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date range:",
                      Sys.Date()-10,
                      Sys.Date()+10)),
    wellPanel(selectInput("Country", "Select a Country:",
                          '')),
    wellPanel(selectInput("State", "Select a State:",
                          '')))
```

Comment: Try to separate things with two observers instead of one (and you should use `reactive({})` to get `ddf`)

Comment: I tried with two observers and `reactive({})` to get `ddf1`, but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's like a conflict in your observer cause it contains `input$Country` as well as an updater for the `Country` input. Then I'd try to split it into two observers, and I'd use a reactive conductor to make `ddf` only once.

```
get_ddf <- reactive({
  df[df$Date>=input$daterange[1] & df$Date<=input$daterange[2],]
})
observe({
  updateSelectInput(session, "Country", choices = get_ddf()$Country)
})
observe({
  ddf1 = subset(get_ddf(), grepl(input$Country, get_ddf()$State))
  updateSelectInput(session, "State", choices =  ddf1$State)  
})
```

Moreover, shouldn't you use the levels of the column rather than the column itself in the `choices` argument ?

```
observe({
  updateSelectInput(session, "Country", choices = levels(droplevels(get_ddf()$Country)))
})
observe({
  ddf1 = droplevels(subset(get_ddf(), grepl(input$Country, get_ddf()$State)))
  updateSelectInput(session, "State", choices =  levels(ddf1$State))  
})
```

If the `Country` and `State` columns are not factors but characters, use `unique()` instead of `levels(droplevels())`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, above both solutions worked. I opted for the second one though.

Comment: Based on above I would like pass the data to another data frame as output. If it is in the observer, How can I send the data frame outside?

Comment: I tried to `assign` a `.GlobalEnv` variable inside `observe`.    `observe({  
      ddf1 = droplevels(subset(get_ddf(), grepl(input$Country, get_ddf()$State)))  
      updateSelectInput(session, "State", choices =  levels(ddf1$State))  
      assign("ddf1",ddf1, envir = .GlobalEnv)
     }) `  `dataset = reactive({  
    ddf1
  })`  but this is printing all states

Comment: Try `reactiveValues()` instead of `assign`. Or make a reactive conductor `get_ddf1` similar to `get_ddf`, this maybe cleaner. Note also that you could use only one reactive conductor returning both `ddf` and `ddf1` in a list.