# R Shiny selectinput box auto filter

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

Does shiny can auto filer data in UI page? like select Site, Title data auto filter by site?

```
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("Site", "Choose a Site:", 
              choices = site),
  selectInput("Title", "Choose a Title:", 
              choices = title,multiple=TRUE),
  selectInput("Job Category", "Choose a Job category:", 
              choices = job_category,multiple=TRUE),
```

>

```
#-----Raw data--------
    Site    Title   Job_Category
1   Wuxi    Sr Manager  Management
2   Wuxi    Manager Management
3   Wuxi    Sr Manager  Management
4   Suzhou  Manager Management
5   Wuxi    Analyst II  Professional
6   Wuxi    Director    Management
7   Wuxi    Manager Management
8   Wuxi    Staff Analyst   Professional
9   Wuxi    Sr Team Lead    Management
10  Wuxi    Manager Management
11  Wuxi    Sr Administrator    Professional
12  Suzhou  Manager Management
13  Suzhou  Sr Analyst  Professional
14  Suzhou  Sr Analyst  Professional
15  Suzhou  Staff Analyst   Professional
16  Suzhou  Sr Analyst  Professional
17  Wuxi    Staff Analyst   Professional
18  Suzhou  Analyst II  Professional
19  Suzhou  Analyst II  Professional
20  Wuxi    Sr Administrator    Professional
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `renderUI` to create the `selectinput` variables in `server.R`. There is exmaple [observe updateSelectInput based on first selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073948/observe-updateselectinput-based-on-first-selection), alternatively you can use `updateSelectInput` in your `observer` statement to update the `selectInput` however I am not sure how to select all the variables based on that. Here's working example below based on the first method. Please note that I created sample data based on the input you have provided.

```
library(shiny)

Site <- NULL
Title <- NULL
Job_Category <- NULL
for (i in 1:50)
{
  Site[i] <- sample(c("Wuxi","Suzhou","Other site"))[1]
  Title[i] <- sample(c("Sr Manager","Manager","Director", "Analyst II","Sr Administrator"))[1]
  Job_Category[i] <- sample(c("Management","Professional"))[1]
}

ui =fluidPage(
  tabPanel("Testing",
           sidebarPanel(
             selectInput("Site", "Choose a Site:", choices = c(Site)),
             uiOutput("varselect2"),uiOutput("varselect3"))))

server = function(input, output, session){

  output$varselect2 <- renderUI({
    cols <- Title[Site %in% input$Site]
    selectInput("vars", "Select Title:",choices=cols, selected=cols, multiple=T)  
  })  

  output$varselect3 <- renderUI({
    cols2 <- Job_Category[Site %in% as.character(input$Site) & Title %in% input$vars]
    selectInput("vars2", "Select Job category:",choices=cols2, selected=cols2, multiple=T)  
  })

}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```